# Problem encountered in react native run android on ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, react-native, ubuntu

I encountered this problem when I tried to run android app, with react native on `ubuntu 20.04`

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
```

with `--verbose` flag for more details.

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/usr/bin/env: ‘sh\r’: No such file or directory
```

any help

Comment: `‘sh\r’:` means you have DOS line endings on a *nix system. `dos2unix problemFile` will fix one file. If you installed a whole package designed for MS-Windows, then you need to go back and find the *nix version and install that instead. Not really a programming Q. More appropriate to [su]. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.